# How to do an if command to format cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am sure this is super basic so apologies.

Does anyone know how to write a command to say if there is data within the cell, then put the '@' symbol at the start of the text.

I.e. cell a1: Tom. cell a2: cell a3:Andy >>>>> a1:@tom a2: a3:@andy

Thank you, Tom.

Comment: `=IF(ISBLANK(A1),"","@" & A1)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without formatting a cell by just concatenating a `@` in front of non-blank cells like this:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1),"",CONCATENATE("@",A1))
```